# How to send ajax without an inputtext in JSF?

Tags: jsf

Here is my view:

```
<h:body>
    <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - hello.xhtml</h3>
    <h:form id="test" prependId="false">
        <h:commandButton value="Increase counter">
            <f:ajax execute="#{user.increaseCounter()}" render="x" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:outputText id="x" value="#{user.counter}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And User.Java:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable {

    private int counter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        counter = 0;
    }

    public void increaseCounter() {
        counter++;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
}
```

So what I expect to see is: everytime I click the Increase Counter Button, an incremented value on screen.

When I debug my application, I see that counter is incremented, however it is not rendered. Why might that be?

Comment: Is it really incremented when you press the button? The code posted so far has namely the major mistake that it does that only when the page with the form is requested.

Comment: Maybe not I tried this For so lıng I am tired and confused.. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I edited my code, it increments in every refresh, not in every button click.. Strange.

Comment: It's not strange if you read the documentation or examples of `<f:ajax execute>` attribute. The code is behaving exactly as you programmed it to do.

Comment: That's probably funny to see that half working but it is logic when we think about it :)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie sorry?

Comment: BalusC pointed you out where you made the mistake, to be more precise, check `execute` and `listener` attributes in documentation.

Comment: @KorayTugay You should write an answer and accept it! Now you probably find that behavior more funny when you understand the mistake :)

Comment: Thanks you actually deserve it but why not. You are right, dumb mistake.. Happens from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments (Mostly from BalusC) OP made a mistake :

```
<f:ajax execute="#{user.increaseCounter()}" render="x" />
```

muse be

```
<f:ajax listener="#{user.increaseCounter()}" render="x" />
```

The behavior he was experiencing that actually the value was incremented not at each click but at render time. This is because at render time his method `increaseCounter()` as it was an EL expression, but of course it was returning nothing so no further execution was done.